# How to sort data in grid/table in Asp.net MVC 4 using client side framework only.(No angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a grid(table) in asp.net MVC 4 in which i get data loaded (like name,data,phoneno...). Now when I click 'name' header , i want my data to be sorted without having any roundtrip to server. 
Is is possible without using AngularJs and only using pure javascript?

any logic would be appreciated rest i'd implement on my own.

Comment: Why would you put [angularjs] tag if you don't want it to be done in angularjs?

Comment: Because I know angularjs users like me would see this post. And i know they might help me.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you do NOT want it in angularjs?

Comment: Have a look at [these examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @maurycy, the project in which i work doesn't use angular. but i'm very much interested in angular but can't use it in it.

Comment: If you give me a bit more structure of your code I'll write a working example for you, is it pure javascript or you do use any framework?

Comment: Its pure MVC 4 project and on client side its using javascript & Jquery only. currently its returning Model from the controller and not any Json object. so is it possible in that way?

or do i have to change the way i have implemented it? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you have a jquery you could reorder the DOM elements with custom sort function, if you can do a fiddle or plnkr that I could work on I'll give you the answer